# Unable to use regular expression against WSL distribution list

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get the default WSL2 distribution name, into a variable, in PowerShell. But, for some reason, I'm struggling to use a regular expression against the output of `wsl`. I am not having this issue with other commands.

`wsl --list` returns 4 array elements:

```
$test = wsl --list | Where-Object { $_ -and $_ -ne ''}
echo $test
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data (Default)
docker-desktop
Ubuntu-20.04
echo $test.Count
```

**Select-String Pattern Fails**

I can pattern match a single letter:

```
echo $test | Select-String -Pattern 'e'

Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data (Default)
docker-desktop
```

But pattern matching 2+ characters returns nothing

```
echo $test | Select-String -Pattern 'ef'
```

**ForEach with Regular Expression**

ForEach with a regular expression works with a single character

```
$test | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -like '*e*') {
        Write-Output $_
    }
}
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data (Default)
docker-desktop
```

But it doesn't work with multiple characters:

```
$test | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -like '*ef*') {
        Write-Output $_
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something simple, but am currently at a loss. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Which PS version are you running this on?

Comment: Did you try : $test | Select-String -Pattern 'ef' | Foreach { Write-Host $_ }

Comment: @Destroy666 - PowerShell version is: 5.1.22621.963 / Desktop

Comment: @jdweng - same result

Comment: Encoding issue. `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` before running your code.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - That was it. Makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Santiago Squarzon in [Unable to use regular expression against WSL distribution list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75848747/unable-to-use-regular-expression-against-wsl-distribution-list?noredirect=1#comment133791491_75848747), this was an encoding issue fixed by adding `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` to the start of the script.